# create virtual field to parent row to check child record exits or not

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables users and manager.
My tables are like this:

[image]

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What's the goal? The question is not clear and provide a bit of code.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt83W.png

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
select user.id,user.name,case when(project.id is null) then 'No' else 'yes'end has_project from user left outer join project on project.user_id = user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Im not available mysql server, but wrote example on mysql, might  fit for you.

```
create table 
       UserTable
(
       id integer,
       name text
);

insert into UserTable select 1, 'abc';
insert into UserTable select 2, 'def';
insert into UserTable select 3, 'ghi';

select
      *
from
    UserTable;



create table 
       ProjectTable
(
       id ineger, 
       user_id integer 
);

insert into ProjectTable select 1, 2;
insert into ProjectTable select 2, 1;
insert into ProjectTable select 3, 1;


select
      *      
from
    ProjectTable;    


select
      u.id,      
      u.name,
      case      
           when p.id not null then 'Yes'
           else 'No'
      end 'HasProject' 

from
    UserTable u   
left join
     ProjectTable p     
on
  u.id = p.user_id
group by
      u.id;
```